# How do I keep doxygen from misparsing unnamed parameters in C++ functions

Tags: c++, doxygen

It is common to leave unused function arguments unnamed in the definition.

E.g.:

```
inline std::string operator "" _s(char const * const op, size_t const) {
    return {op};
}
```

In such a case doxygen 1.8.12 seems to mistake (the last part of) the type for the parameter name:

```
warning: The following parameters of … are not documented:
  parameter 'const'
```

Is there a way to get rid of this warning without turning `WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED` off and without wrapping the parameter in `\cond`, `\endcond`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doxygen 1.8.15 does no longer have this problem.